# Swift return result of function calls

Tags: swift

I'm completing some exercism exercises. One is a Binary tree (although the context is not relevant to the question as I have experienced this previously in Swift)

I would like to put the following function on one line as:

```
func allData () -> [Int] {
    return ( left?.allData() ?? [] ) + [data] + ( right?.allData() ?? [] )
}
```

But the error is 'Int' is not convertible to '[Int]'

Ok, but splitting into separate lines is fine:

```
func allData () -> [Int] {
    let leftdata = left?.allData() ?? []
    let rightdata = right?.allData() ?? []
    return ( leftdata ) + [data] + ( rightdata )
}
```

In fact it will compile with either the left data, right data and [data], but not both.

Within exercism I can see that people did not solve this in one line.

So why is

```
return ( left?.allData() ?? [] ) + [data] + ( right?.allData() ?? [] )
```

invalid?

Comment: what allData() method returns?

Comment: An array of Integer (in effect, the data in a tree using Inorder)

Comment: What are the declarations for `left`, `right` and `data`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this often with multiple entries added together.  The compiler's type processing sometimes gets confused when combining optionals and non optional types (3 or more) in a single statement.

There is a very similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/43595162/5237560

and another one here:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/42568446/5237560

In short, the compiler needs help in some cases which are not detected as "too complex" but actually result in the wrong data type being inferred.

Answer (score 1):

It won't answer your "why" question, but this might offer you an alternative if you want to keep it as a one-liner:

```
func allData() -> [Int] {
    return [left?.allData() ?? [], [data], right?.allData() ?? []].flatMap { $0 }
}
```

or

```
func allData() -> [Int] {
    // The first flatMap removes nil elements and the second flattens the array
    return [left?.allData(), [data], right?.allData()].flatMap { $0 }.flatMap { $0 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, xcode does not compile a statement because it is too complex to be compiled n a reasonable time. Therefore, splitting the statement solves the issue.

Comment: Interesting. But that usually results in a message to that effect; in this case the statement is entirely different. Do you have a source for your idea?

Comment: I never had the same case u had. However, Xcode never fails to amaze me with errors that are in some cases invalid!